# Select a specific node in umbraco

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have this select statement that selects all of the child nodes of *what we do*. How would I now select a specific one? See code below:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::Homepage//WhatWeDoItems [@isDoc]">

</xsl:for-each>
```

There are four items in what we do. They have the document type of `WhatWeDoItems` and they are:

- Corporate
- Festival
- Venue Hire
- Private Party

I need to select each one of them individually in order to display them on the home page.
Am I going in the right direction or is there a better solution?

Comment: so do you want a specific node or all of them - it's not very clear...

Comment: I just want one say 'corporate'

Comment: hard to say without looking at your input document.

Comment: the homepage has four sections corporate festivals venue hire and private party the description for each of these i would like to come from the what we do pages which can be found by clicking on the what we to link and then clicking more for the individual node hope this makes sense? Thanks

Comment: Very poorly defined question. No XML document provided. Not sure when you are speaking of "hild nodes" and "sections" what exactly you mean. Please, edit and improve. As it is now, you are wasting your time and, more importantly, the time of many people trying to understand this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably post the whole XML, but if I understand correctly you can just use

```
<xsl:value-of select="$currentPage//WhatWeDoItems/corporate" />
```

Just create a XSLT macro with the code above and insert the macro in out template.

If you don't know how to do that look at the [video tutorials](http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials):

Comment: i need to grab the values from the node corporate and display them how would i go about doing this?

Comment: just create an XSLT macro and insert the macro in your template